# how to setup Hosting Node.js API as a freelancer?

Tags: node.js, api, hosting, freelancer.com-api

I am a Freelancer i need help with hosting my API, I'm hosting my frontend at firebase as it is a free service but not sure where to host my API , can i get some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Today, there are many options to host applications free of cost, some of them are free to extend where one can handle few real users also.

I will try to mention them as per my favorite and time to deploy

1. Heroku:- simplest, free forever (limited dynos read document), https://www.heroku.com/nodejs
2. AWS:- All one can need in their lifetime for any type of APP, 1-year free
3. Google Cloud:- same as AWS, 1-year free tier
4. Azure:- same as AWS, 1-year free tier
5. Digital Ocean:- simpler than AWS, free for 2 months

Almost all cloud provider today provide a free tier, just choose the one you like and good to go,

Just keep in mind to architect your application in such a way that tomorrow you can easily switch from cloud provider if you intend (due to cost, service, feature etc.)